# How to map a directory to a folder on file system in apache?

Tags: apache-http-server

i have some folders:

`~/dev/php/public` and `~/dev/php/private~`

in apache, how can i make `domain.com/php/public` go to `~/dev/php/public`? and the same with private? they are on the same domain so i dont need to create a virtual host or anything..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup there a re a few ways of doing it -

1. Modify your Apache Document Root or
2. Use mod_rewrite to rewrite the location or
3. Create a symlink in your directory tree to your /home/username/dev/php
4. Use mod_alias (alias)

I believe mod_alias is the most likely the best solution - so something like the following might do you:

```
Alias /php/public /home/USERNAME/dev/php/public
Alias /php/private /home/USERNAME/dev/php/private
```

In your apache config.  (This assumes that the home directory of the owner is "/home/USERNAME")